# Select "src" value with XPath to HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm on a development process of a crawling engine. My program crawls websites through Xpath with HtmlAgilityPack. I need to get some image src tag's directly. You can see my simple code below which is not working correctly, thanks in advice!

*PS: Please ignore " char problem, XPath patterns are provided by database.*

```
Agility.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@id="product_photo"]/@src");
```

And this is the line i need to crawl (the `*...*` part shows block to extract

```
<img id="product_photo" src="*/images/thumb/4400/10280/st.jpg*">
```

Some pages provide image in meta tags so `.Attributes["src"]` wont work.

UPDATE: You can see my query and result here[image: Query]

Comment: What does `//img[@id="product_photo"]/@src` return?  Also, have you tried with single quotes: `//img[@id='product_photo']/@src`?

Comment: I also suggest to use "//img[@id='product_photo']/@src"

Comment: It returns HtmlNode object but I want to use just src (or could be content or somethingelse) as a string and sinle quotes didn't work.

Comment: Can you try escaping the inner quotes and see what happens: `"//img[@id=\"product_photo\"]/@src"`.  Lastly if that doesn't work, try prepending with a `.`: `".//img[@id=\"product_photo\"]/@src"`.

Comment: It returns HtmlNode object but I want to use just src (or could be content or somethingelse) as a string. If I use `Agility.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@id="product_photo"]/@src").Attributes["src"].Value;` then it works. But i can not use .Attributes

Comment: Can you use `.GetAttributeValue`?  See [this page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/354761) for an example.

Comment: No, because it depends on source html, sometimes image is in a meta tag like `<meta property="og:image" itemscope="image" content="http://www.XXX.com/ZZZ.jpg" />` so I can not use attributes.

Comment: How about using an `OR` statement to add another XPath to handle the images in the meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

You cann't get the value of "src" or any other attributes in using:

```
Agility.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(yourXpath);
```

**Just** by using:

```
string s=Agility.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(yourXpath).value;
```

It's because XPath cann't return value of an attribute by SelectSingleNode() func in HtmlAgilityPack class. So you must use `SelectSingleNode(yourXpath).value` or use Regex after the pharsing to get just the "src" without the outerText.